# "ps -fC tmux" command does not show tmux process

Tags: command-line, tmux, ps

I am running a tmux server. When I checked the process, I can see the tmux process:

```
# ps -ef | grep tmux | grep -v grep
root        4129    1424  0 17:47 pts/0    00:00:00 tmux
root        4131       1  0 17:47 ?        00:00:34 tmux
```

However, when I wanted to check the command that run tmux, I can't see any process:

```
# ps -fC tmux
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
```

The -C option works for other processes but it does not show tmux process. What is the reason? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

ps -f prints the command line, ps -C is searching by the command name.  These are often the same, but they don't have to be.

In your setup if you tried

```
ps -o comm,cmd 4129
```

you will see the two fields. The command name is the first column with the command  line being the second.